# Vertically Centering Links in inside Div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

http://www.fccorp.us/index.php

The vertical column to the left is my site menu system. The column is a div with a height:100%, and the different details are div's laid over it.

The buttons are DIV's with blank buttons as backgrounds, with links on them. I have two different size buttons, the big one 60px tall and the small one 30px. Using CSS can I get the links to be centered vertically regardless of the height of the button's DIV?

I've looked here and used a few CSS sites & Android Apps. The site here suggests I can't, but I can't understand why the CSS group would not create a vertically centering function since it seems so needed.

Am I just missing something or am I really trying to get something that isn't available with CSS?

Comment: There are many methods for vertical alignment:  http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ or http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off your site, you can use `line-height` to adjust the vertical positioning of the text.

Try applying this to your 30px tall links:

```
line-height: 30px;
```

And this for the 60px tall:

```
line-height: 60px;
```

Additionally, you should not be nesting `<div>` tags within `<a>` tags.

Comment: Or he can use padding top and bottom instead set a fixed height.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
.menubuttonthick{line-height:60px;}
.menubuttonthin{line-height:30px;}
```

That will center all of your links.

On another note, currently you have the following structure:

```
<a href="#">
  <div>text</div>
</a>
```

That is invalid HTML. I'm not a "HTML must be valid at all times" type of guy, but when you can fix it that easily, I think it wouldn't hurt making it valid. You should use the following:

```
<div>
  <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: "That is invalid HTML" <- are you sure about that?  http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: Thanks much, it centered the text just like I needed. I also took your advice about teh nested div's. I knew it wasn't technically valid, but it worked. Unfortunately now I have some artifact generated from moving the class to the <a> tag. Any thoughts?

Comment: @J.D. Add the following css to your thick menu item: `display:block;height:60px;width:170px;` I'm sure you can figure out the css for the thin menu items. :)

Comment: @cimmanon HTML5, even though widely used (I use the doctype as well) is still experimental and surely isn't supported in older browsers. And for a website like above it seems like overkill to use something like Modernizer, don't you think? It can cause issues, I don't know if it will, better just make it "valid" in the first place :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked. Now, would you mind explaining it to me? I don't understand since the div... nevermind, its because I moved the class to an inline element.

Comment: Cimmanon... I'm sorry, this was my first question, I'm still learning how this site works, no offense was intended. I chose this one because it went further with the mention of the invalid code.

Comment: @user2019515 I never suggested Modernizr nor did I suggest leaving the markup the way it is, I just pointed out that you were wrong about it being invalid because it *is* valid (for the HTML5 doctype anyway).

Comment: You're not required to accept the first answer, you should accept the one which you think is the best answer. To be honest I'm a little bit offended right now because Axel just edit his answer and added the invalid nested issue in his answer and because. I'm sure he can explain it to you what the problem is, if not I'll answer it tomorrow because I got to go right now.

Comment: @cimmanon I never said you suggested using modernizer but if you wanted to display it properly you should be using it if you don't want to change it. But yes, it is valid in HTML5, thanks for telling me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS. It will work regardless of the height of your buttons:

```
.menubar a div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: True... but on the other hand it is going to cause many other properties to behave in often-unexpected ways (width, height and margin at the very least are affected by the _table-cell_ display setting).